# How make skin files work with Asp.net mvc 4 and Devexpress 14.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I want to set my GridView settings for whole web application so that I dont need to do it for every page I create.

I do as described at https://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument14816 . I use "Use site-related URLs" and not "Only skin files". It creates in my `App_Themes` folder the theme. Then I add the following:

In global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DevExpressHelper.Theme = "PlasticBlue";
    }
```

In web.config:

```
 <pages validateRequest="false" clientIDMode="AutoID" theme="PlasticBlue">
 ... 
 <devExpress>
         <themes theme="" enableThemesAssembly="false" styleSheetTheme="" />
 </devExpress>
```

In _Layout.cshtml

```
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(
        new StyleSheet
            {
  ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout, Theme = "PlasticBlue"
  ...
```

In App_Themes/PlasticBlue/MVCxGridView.skin`

```
<dxmvc:MVCxGridView runat="server" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/PlasticBlue/{0}/styles.css" CssPostfix="PlasticBlue" >
<Settings ShowFilterBar="Visible"></Settings>
```

And I create my view with the Grid :

```
GridViewExtension grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "GridViewjjjjjj";

        settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";
      ...
```

And it does not show the Filter bar. What do I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do **NOT** specify the **DevExpressHelper.Theme** property in the **Global.asax.cs** (i.e. do **NOT** use the DevExpress Theming approach):

```
//DevExpressHelper.Theme = "PlasticBlue";
```

But specify the Theme via the **Web.config -> pages -> theme** property (i.e., use the ASP.NET Theming approach):

```
<pages theme="PlasticBlue">
```